# What one can do if he is forced to violate NDA in work practice?

Tags: work-experience, non-disclosure-agreement

Is there any advice for the following situation happened in Finland?

I was in an educational program for unemployed people. They asked me to sign an NDA. One point was that I can't remove the files or programs on the laptop they gave for rent. But the program had also work practice which was asked to write another NDA that says I can't reveal the data I got from the practice. Now the situation is that I have a laptop with data files and whether I leave it or remove from SSD, I have violated either of the NDA.

Comment: Your description of the second NDA is rather vague. What does reveal data mean? Does that mean publicly expose it? Or you have to remove it? Or you can't keep it after use? Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you have to leave the data on the laptop, the solution is to not allow the laptop into the hands of people that shouldn't see the data. If you don't know who that is, speak with whomever is organising this.

Comment: Reading between the lines, I think you are meant to return the laptop in the state in which you got it. Move any documents you created into something that you own. Worst case, email them to yourself.

Comment: Nice username! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I think you may be taking this too literally.**

The laptop agreement was probably not intended to prevent you ever removing any files that you stored on the laptop. It was probably intended to prevent you harming the laptop by removing files that were on it when it was given you. Preventing you ever deleting anything was almost certainly going to involve them getting to see your personal information.

Read the original NDA more carefully and check whether it really says you can't remove anything ever, or just can't remove anything that was on it when you were given it. It it is the latter then just erase the confidential files from your work practice.

Even if it seems to read that you can't erase anything ever, that's probably a mistake. Go to the people who loaned you the laptop and check with them if you are allowed to erase confidential files from your work practice. I'm betting they say yes.